# Linux - C Socket to "take over" all packets == force OS to ignore all packets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, debian

I'm using Debian OS.
I'm writing a network emulation and I want to get all the packets and stop Debian
from responding to ANY of the sent packets.

So far I have a socket opened and I get all the packets but Debian is also getting 
them and responds(ICMP pings mostly)

I want Debian to ignore/ not receive any of the packets.
How can I do it? Debian wise or socket-wise I really don't mind.

Thanks
Despairy

Edit:

So far :

```
echo "0" >  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_redirects 

echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all

echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/accept_source_route

echo "0" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/send_redirects

echo "1"> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_ignore

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

Solved part of the issue.
Linux stopped answering Ping requests and ICMP at all(stopped forwarding as well)

Now i'm trying to avoid DNS responses, i think i found the answers i was looking for
ill give you and update.

Comment: this is some stuff i found and tried but still sniffing on wireshark showed it isnt enough.

Comment: what is "this" that you found? also you shouldn't add comments to your own questions...simply update your Q

Comment: what do you mean with "I want Debian to not receive any of the packets"? since you are *on* debian, this means that you won't receive any packets (since "debian" cannot pass them to you)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment but it is too long to come out the way I want.  Sorry.

You have to do something draconian like shutdown the TCP/IP stack to stop "everything", so that cannot be what you mean or really want.  Then you could not get/send packets.

On problems like this if you tell us what you are trying to accomplish, and assume you do not have your own way of doing it (you believe you do have one), then describe the problem rather than the troubles with your solution you will almost always get good answer.  What you describe appears to be a complete no-go IMO.

To do what you are describing you would have to interpose some kind of router between debian and the network, that redirects all incoming packets to your debian box's one port.   snort kind of does this but does not redirect packets, this kind of packet sniffing is enabled by promiscuous mode setting on the NIC.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else needs a solution:

The simplest way I found to avoid my operating system from replying and requesting packets
is to use UFW.

By installing UFW, it is easy to block all incoming and outgoing packets from your operating system.
with UFW enabled, open sockets in C will still transmit any packet given.

```
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw default deny outgoing
sudo ufw enable
```

and to disable:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Enjoy